# Authentication Users On BlogEngine.NET Via A Third Party Web Service And Other Customisations

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogengine.net

Goodday people,

I have a challenge with BlogEngine.NET

I have an entire database of users, far different from BlogEngine's DB. I am currently consuming a web service that authenticates said users in another application

I do have some other customization/extensions I'd like to do with BlogEngine.NET, like -

- Authenticating users via the web service rather than using the table
  from the BlogEngine DB.
- Inserting user name from the web service into the User table in
  BlogEngine DB.
- Assigning users from the web service user roles, and    allowing them
  post.

I understand the login.aspx.cs has a method(`LoginUser_OnAuthenticate()`) that authenticates the user to see if the username and passwords match those in the data-store. The `LoginUser_OnAuthenticate` method in login.aspx.cs calls the `AuthenticateUser` method in Security.cs.

What I don't understand is where (what aspx file) does the `Response.Redirect()` method to direct the user to if the match is correct? What does `context.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);` return?

I'm sorry, I'm still new to C#. Just trying to wrap my head around this.

I don't know if anyone has worked on something like this and would like to be put through.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed this months ago, writing a wrapper round the  `AuthenticateUser()` method, that authenticates via the in-house API, then goes to the BlogEngine DB to see if that user exists. If the user exists, the user is redirected to the homepage. So in login.aspx.cs, I replaced `Login_AuthenticateUser()` with the wrapper I had written.